# how i can use this curl command in php?

Tags: php, curl, port

I'm trying to send a file that inputs from the user on my website port 80 and send this file to execute on a server by using this curl command:

```
curl -v --form input=@./file.pdf localhost:8080/processHeaderDocument -o ./file.xml
```

i try to do this but it is not response anything

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

how do I use this command in php? Is it will occur problem to send a file over port 80 to 8080?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope this solve you problem.

```
// initialise the curl request
$request = curl_init('http://example.com/');

// send a file
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath('example.txt')
    ));

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);

// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

Below is the link.
http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/

Comment: I try this code and seem that server can't find the file path with this error
[ERROR] org.grobid.service.process.GrobidRestProcessFiles: An unexpected exception occured: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] org.grobid.core.utilities.IOUtilities: Error while deleting the temporary file: 
java.lang.NullPointerException